# Postresql, проблемы с вводом

Tags: python, база-данных, postgresql

```
id = '42586566'
mark = "5 4 5- П 2"
mark = mark.replace("П",'')
mark = mark.replace(" ",'')
lesson = "Алгебра"
mark = str(mark)
id = str(id)
try:
    cursor.execute('ALTER TABLE lessons ADD COLUMN %s text' % (lesson))
except:
    print("already added")
try:
    mas = (lesson,id,mark)
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO lessons (userid, %s) VALUES ( %s , %s )",mas)
except:
    bin = 1
    print("Error2")
mas = (lesson,mark ,id)
cursor.execute("UPDATE lessons SET %s = %s WHERE userid=%s", mas) #проблема
```

Везде, где можно, отрабатывают except. И выводится следующее сообщение об ошибке:

```
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "'Алгебра'"
LINE 1: UPDATE lessons SET 'Алгебра' = '545-2' WHERE userid='425865...
```

Я не понимаю, где именно у меня нарушение синтаксиса/опечатка.
Помогите пожалуйста корректно написать.

Comment: Наверное должно получаться так `UPDATE lessons SET "Алгебра" = '545-2' ...`. Т.е. в запросах названия полей надо заключать в двойные кавычки.

Comment: @Sergey Ну да. Но непонятно каким образом "'Алгебра'" получается в тройных кавычках. и притом я даже сделал преобразование в строку, на всякий случай - не помогло.

Comment: Это в сообщении об ошибке кажется, что в тройных. В запросе очевидно в одинарных, что рассматривается как текст. Имена полей должны быть либо без кавычек, либо в двойных кавычках.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Измените последние 2 строки:

```
mas = (mark ,id)
cursor.execute('UPDATE lessons SET "{}" = %s WHERE userid=%s'.format(lesson), mas)
```

Но, вообще говоря, имена столбцов лучше не делать русскими. Если необходимо в выборке получать колонки с отформатированным русским именем используйте `as`.

Пример:

```
SELECT algebra as "Алгебра"
FROM lessons
```

Comment: cursor.execute('UPDATE lessons SET "{}" = %s WHERE userid=%s'.format(lesson), mas)
psycopg2.errors.InFailedSqlTransaction: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block

Comment: Чёт не оч. Но за идею спасибо, поэксперементирую. А про русские имена знаю. Просто пар(сю/шу) русскоязычный сайт

Comment: Спасибо! Очень выручил! А ошибку я ловил, потому что забыл base.commit() поставить!